# How can I make GTM tags fire "once per page" on a single page application?

Tags: single-page-application, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I have a single page web app with a third party marketing tool I need to track. The tool implements a form.

What I need to know is:

1. How many people started filling in the form on a certain page type, i. e. first-clicked any of the fields (once per page)

All of the fields share the same class (at least partly). So I created a trigger that fires on

```
"[click classes] starts with [classname part]" AND 
"[page url] contains [pagetype]".
```

This trigger is used for an event tag A with the "tag firing options: once per page", so that I do not get all of the element clicks, but only the relevant amount of starts which is per page. *

2. How many people successfully submit a form (once per page)

This was a little more tricky, since "successfully" means that I am not interested in simple button clicks, since those could also end in error messages if someone missed filling in a required field. Also, I do not get a success page, but a success message. The div this message appears in is always there, it is just not filled until submission. I solved this by creating a custom variable defining that element and an "element visibility trigger" that fires on

```
"[page url] contains [pagetype]" AND 
"[custom variable]" equals [success message]"

+ DOM change observance.
```

This trigger is used for event tag B with the "tag firing options: once per page". This is necessary, since the marketing tool allows multiple successful submits of the very same form (please don't ask). Therefore, I need to restrict this to once per page as well. *

***) Now here's my struggle:** This setup would be working fine for a multi page application with a standard page view tracking. However, I need to have my standard page view trigger to fire at history event changes, and this crashes my setup. I don't know how to restrict the two new event tags A+B for firing "once per page" if I don't have actual page views.

I cannot imagine that I am the only person who needs to solve this case. However, either everyone else just knows how to or I am not searching well enough - I don't find anything on this matter.

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this? 
Any slightest hint would be very much appreciated! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do I understand well, that you want to fire tag A at most once per page fragment, and tag B once per page fragment? Or do you need them to fire at most once per user session, regardless of pages (fragments) visited?

Comment: The forms I need to track appear on a certain page type that I can define with a certain url fragment. I need the actual amount of forms started and submitted, regardless of users or sessions. So yes, I need those two new tags A+B to fire exactly once per page (in case the forms are used).